# Could not find the correct Provider - Flutter ChangeNotificationProvider

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this ProductScreen Widget**

I'm getting this error trying to use MVVM in my flutter app. There is a provider above the ProductScreen that is ProductListViewModel and it should work in my opinion. If you can give me feedback I would appreciate it.

**ChangeNotifierProvider usage:**

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "Products",
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home:
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => ProductListViewModel(),
          child: ProductScreen(),
        )
    );
}
}
```

**ProductListViewModel**

```
class ProductListViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {

  List<ProductViewModel> products = List<ProductViewModel>();

  Future<void> fetchProducts(String keyword) async {
    final results =  await Webservice().fetchProducts(keyword);
    this.products = results.map((item) => ProductViewModel.fromProduct(item)).toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**ProductScreen**

```
class ProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductScreenState createState() => _ProductScreenState();
}

class _ProductScreenState extends State<ProductScreen> {

  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Provider.of<ProductListViewModel>(context, listen: false).fetchProducts("");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final vm = Provider.of<ProductListViewModel>(context);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Movies")
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                    if(value.isNotEmpty) {
                      vm.fetchProducts(value);
                      _controller.clear();
                    }
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Search",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      border: InputBorder.none
                  ),

                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: ProductList(products: vm.products))
            ])
        )

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my side. It looks like the problem is not in above code?

Comment: @yellowgray the problem was an import statement was translated to "C://..." structure by android studio, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap MaterialApp widget inside of ChangeNotifierProvider widget.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (ctx) => ProductListViewModel(),
        child: MaterialApp(
        title: "Products",
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: ProductScreen(),
        )
    );
}
}
```

or you can define it as mentioned in [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ProductListViewModel(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "Products",
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: ProductScreen(),
    );
}
}
```

Also check out this medium [blog](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-state-management-with-provider-notifylisteners-x-streamprovider-part-1-edba795d4937) for more info about provider, multiprovider and consumer.

Comment: Wrapping MaterialApp widget didn't work, getting the same error.

Comment: @SilverKappa i think its my mistake use different context variable rather than context in create argument i have updated context with ctx.

Comment: Made the change, still the same error persists: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ProductListViewModel> above this ProductScreen Widget